# Do precision-recall curves have a constant shape/pattern?

Tags: machine-learning, model-evaluations

I know ROC curve always looks like a stair shape and that I can evaluate AUC of ROC. And I know I can compute AUC of ROC curve to compare which model is better. What I wonder is:

- Does precision-recall curves have a constant shape/pattern?
- Can I compute AUC of PR curve to compare which model is better?
- If not, how can you compare models by PR curves?

Answer (score 2):

> I wonder if PR curve(Precision-Recall curve) has a constant shape(pattern)?

For a model that is better than random (having a ROC above tpr = fpr line), which is mostly the case, precision and recall *roughly* have an inverse relationship. Therefore, we should expect that a (precision, recall) curve generally decreases (checkout [this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/49117/67328) on the relationship between precision and recall).

> Can I compute AUC of PR curve to compare which model is better?

Yes. It is even preferred over AUC (of ROC) when classes are *imbalanced* in the test set (for example, check out [this blog](https://acutecaretesting.org/en/articles/precision-recall-curves-what-are-they-and-how-are-they-used), [this Kaggle notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/lct14558/imbalanced-data-why-you-should-not-use-roc-curve), and [this 2015 paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4349800/)). Here is an image from the referenced blog

[image]

which shows that PRC (right), unlike ROC (left), is robust to imbalanced classes.

And here is a quote from the referenced Kaggle notebook (texts in brackets are added by me):

> ROC curve is not a good visual illustration for highly imbalanced
>   data, because the False Positive Rate ( False Positives / Total Real
>   Negatives ) does not drop drastically *[i.e., does not produce a lower curve with smaller AUC]* when the Total Real Negatives is
>   huge *[i.e., negative class is much larger than positive class]*.
>
> Whereas Precision ( True Positives / (True Positives + False
>   Positives) ) is highly sensitive to False Positives and is not
>   impacted by a large total real negative denominator.

which is illustrated as below

[image]

emphasizing on the black model (black curve) that is shown to be powerful in ROC  but not that much in PRC; given that negative to positive ratio is around 600 (the ratio should be 1 when classes are balanced).

Answer (score 0):

The perfect PR curve is upper right hand corner. You can compute compute the AUC of PR curve to compare models, and similar to an AUROC, a higher AU the PR curve would be better. Another option would be to choose a cutoff and compare methods there.

http://www.chioka.in/differences-between-roc-auc-and-pr-auc/